# TFS + Git Azure Deployments Failed "Build Not Found"

Tags: git, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, tfs, msbuild

I've been debugging an issue for a day now and can't seem to figure it out. Perhaps someone else has run into something similar and can shed some light?

Trying to follow this guide for configuring Azure and TFS : http://pauloortins.com/how-to-automatically-deploy-a-team-foundation-service-git-project-on-azure-step-by-step/

The issue is in Azure the deployment tries to build and run but fails and when I click view log it will give me a 500 error "Build not found: vstfs:///Build/Build/10" (the 10 increments each time I try to deploy).

It's been a two day challenge and I am at a lost as it is all new to me this TFS stuff. I apologize if I lack any more information, I'll be happy to add it if I know what to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Scott Guthrie's blog post from last week http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/11/04/windows-azure-import-export-hard-drives-vm-acls-web-sockets-remote-debugging-continuous-delivery-new-relic-billing-alerts-and-more.aspx and search for TFS. It's now officially supported - no need for things like modified msbuild parameters.